# Can't ping static IP from outside

Tags: windows-vista, static-ip

I have a static IP assigned to my laptop.

However when I ping the static IP from outside any machine the static IP is not pinging. I am using Windows Vista. Are there any settings on Vista for pinging static IPs from outside?

Comment: You have to give us more information. How your network setup looks like? How is your laptop connected to Internet? Do you have firewall/gateway?

Comment: Also have you got just static or public ip?

Comment: Is that static IP your local or internet IP? We need more details, perhaps examples...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to ping your laptop from within the same network, you might need to allow ICMP requests (Pings) through your Vista Firewall first. 
See [this post at thehowtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/allow-pings-icmp-echo-request-through-your-windows-vista-firewall/) for a good step-by-step guide.

If that doesn't help, describe your network setup and from where exactly you are trying to ping your machine.

Comment: I am trying to ping my static IP from outside my LAN

Answer (score 0):

When you say ping from outside, do you mean outside the local network?

If so then you will need to tell your router to forward the port, say 80 for http, or all ports to the IP.

Look for port forwarding in your modem/router setup.

Comment: hi, I didnt get this. If I give my static IP to my Linux machine then it ping from outside my LAN. But when I give the same static IP to to vista machine, the same static IP not pinging from my outside LAN. please reply me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin rights on the firewall between your LAN and Internet you need to NAT your Public IP to your Private IP and allow ICMP messages to pass both ways at the firewall level on the router and also at your laptop firewall.

Answer (score -1):

Please view: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

The internal network (LAN) is a different network from 'the internet'.